# No type named 'iterator_category' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<int* const>'

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, iterator-traits

I'm writing a custom vector class:

```cpp
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
class vector {
 public:
  using value_type = T;
  using pointer = value_type*;
  using iterator = pointer;
  using const_iterator = const iterator;
  using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

  auto crbegin() const -> const_reverse_iterator {
    return const_reverse_iterator(data_);
  }

 private:
  pointer data_{};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  vector<int> v;
  auto i = v.crbegin();

  return 0;
}
```

When compiling the code above, I get this error (on GCC and MSVC):

```
error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<int* const>’
```

The error goes away when I change the reverse iterator definition to `std::reverse_iterator<const T*>`. What's the difference compared to `std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be reduced to this:

```
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
class vector {
 public:
  using value_type = T;
  using pointer = value_type*;
  using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const pointer>;

  auto crbegin() const -> const_reverse_iterator {
    return const_reverse_iterator(data_);
  }

 private:
  pointer data_{};
};

int main() {
  vector<int> v;
  auto i = v.crbegin();
  (void) i;
  return 0;
}
```

And the error message from clang makes the nature of the problem clearer:

`no type named 'reference' in 'std::iterator_traits<int *const>'`
                                                   `^^^^^^^^^^`

And so we see that what you thought was a `const *int` (i.e. the pointed-to object is `const`) is in fact an `int *const` (i.e the pointer itself is `const`).

Here's a simple fix:

```
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
class vector {
 public:
  using value_type = T;
  using pointer = value_type*;
  using const_pointer = const value_type*;
  using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_pointer>;

  auto crbegin() const -> const_reverse_iterator {
    return const_reverse_iterator(data_);
  }

 private:
  pointer data_{};
};

int main() {
  vector<int> v;
  auto i = v.crbegin();
  (void) i;
  return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LG4jVAquhdAQE3kC)

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an idea why `const pointer` would evalute to `int* const` instead of `const int*` as the order suggests?

Comment: Not sure, sorry, I'm no language lawyer.  You could post a separate question focussed on only that and tag it appropriately.

Comment: @jsmolka This is why people suggest writing using the "east const" style, so you don't make this issue. `pointer const` is `int* const` - it's the `pointer` that's `const`, not anything into it. With "west const" it makes it seem like `const pointer` gives you `const int*` (as simple test substitution would do) but you're applying _top-level_ `const`, not inner `const`.